# How to pull only specific json object field value in php?

Tags: php, json

I am working on a php code as shown below:

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($episode);echo "</pre>";
```

The above php code displays the following o/p:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [air_date] => 2019-04-15 07:15:00
    [air_duration] => 9900
    [schedule_id] => 4220986
    [program_id] => 23
)
```

Now on doing `print_r($episode->air_date);` it displays the following o/p:

2019-04-15 07:15:00

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make here `print_r($episode->air_date);` so that it displays only date, not the time.

Answer (score 1):

you can wrapper

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime ($episode->air_date));
print_r(date('Y-m-d', strtotime ($episode->air_date)));
```

Comment: I believe that this one won't work

Comment: sory for mistake this one i correct

```echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2019-04-15 07:15:00'));```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to print, you could just print the substring from the beginning to the position of the first space:

`print(substr($episode->air_date, 0, strpos($episode->air_date, ' ')));`

Answer (score 0):

Running the following code you get:

```
$date = "2019-04-15 07:15:00";
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

output: 2019-04-15

This will return a false value:

```
$date = "2019-04-15 07:15:00";
echo date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

output: 1970-01-01